# Value Returned from Angular JS $resource POST Not Matching Server Output

Tags: angularjs

I have a resource factory with a POST method called update:

```
PnrApp.factory('Feed', function ($resource, $cacheFactory, $q, $rootScope) {
var Feed = $resource('api/feeds/:post', { post: 'post' }, {
            get: { method:'GET' },  
            update: { method: 'POST' }

        });
return Feed;
```

});

When I call the method it POSTs the data to the server as expected:

```
    $rootScope.toggleStar = function (post, feedname) {
    var updated = Feed.update(post);
    this.child.StarId = updated.StarId;
}
```

And the server returns the correct values (notice the StarId in this json):

```
{"Name":"13 Ways to Act Like A Business Owner","ItemDate":"June 6, 2013","Url":"/post/13-Ways-to-Act-Like-A-Business-Owner-Stop-Acting-Like-an-Advisor-All-the-Time-(6-min-03-sec).aspx","StarImg":"bulletstar-on.png","StarId":1324,"StarDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","FeedCount":0,"FeedId":19,"SourceIcon":null,"IsBroken":false,"ItemId":"01"}
```

However, if you look at var updated's return value for StarId, notice how it's "0":

[image]
[image]

Can someone explain why this is, and how I can get at the return values in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var updated = Feed.update(post);` makes an async call to the server and returns immedaitly and the `updated` object gets updated as soon as the server returns the data. So I guess you try to access the updated.StarId too early. From the [angular doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means ththeat in most case one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

Try something like this:

```
$rootScope.toggleStar = function (post, feedname) {
  var updated = Feed.update(post, function(f) {
    this.child.StarId = f.StarId;
  });      
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, and I've read that in the docs, but I can't seem to find the syntax to get the value when it finally is returned. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Getting closer. this.child.StarId = f.StarId -- f.StarId now holds the returned value but this.child.StarId throws error: Cannot set property 'StarId' of undefined

Comment: Yeah, the `this` is now in the callback context. One solution is to define `var that = this;` outside the callback and then assign to `that` inside the callback